# Can I see word strengths when learning Danish with Duolingo?

Tags: duolingo, danish

As far as I know, in some languages in Duolingo (used via web browser) it is possible to see the strengths of individual words.

Is Danish one of these languages, and if yes, how can I see the individual word strengths?

---

Word strength, in Duolingo, measures how well the program assumes you know the word in questions. The strength goes down as time passes, and goes up as you practice the word. The speed of decay depends on how well you succeed at the exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duolingo does not have word strengths for Danish. Currently, that feature has only been rolled out to only the most popular languages (Spanish, French, Italian, German, and Portuguese).

*(Thanks to @Turpidude for the list.)*

Comment: Do you have some source with the list of languages for which the feature has been rolled out, or some other relevant source for the claim?

Comment: @Tommi the feature is available for the courses done by Duolingo, so French, Spanish, Italian, German and Portuguese. See also this thread in the Duolingo forum which contains a trick which sometimes seems to work. https://www.duolingo.com/comment/21822399 I've stopped using DL some time ago, so this might be no longer 100% valid.

Comment: I could no longer find an authoritative link for a statement about which languages support a word list, but a search for "duolingo original languages/courses words" (or something similar) will result in the same answers.

Comment: @TommiBrander I speak from personal experience.

Comment: @Turpidude Here is a link to a list confirming what you and fi12 have been saying, not by a Duolingo Admin but definitely by a very well respected moderator. So this should be quite trustworthy information. It . The comment is specifically in reference to the word tab and why it is missing from various courses: https://www.duolingo.com/comment/14769613$comment_id=14775967

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have a 'Word' tab for your Duolingo Danish course, then either Danish doesn't have one, or you are part of an A/B test and your 'Word' tab is deactivated.

What you can do for a workaround is go to the [**Duolingo Wiki** Userscripts](http://duolingo.wikia.com/wiki/Duolingo_Userscripts) page and install the **DuoTweak** userscript (follow the instructions under "How to install scripts"). Since the recent rewrite of Duolingo this userscript has unfortunately become almost useless, but it still works on the discussion forum (i.e. click the 'Discussion' tab) and will make the 'Word' tab available to you for *any* course, even if you are part of an A/B test deactivating your 'Word' tab.

**EDIT**: So as for the question in the title, "Can I see word strengths when learning Danish with Duolingo?": ***Yes, using the DuoTweak userscript it is possible*** (at least for the time being).

**EDIT**: As of Nov 19th, 2017 **DuoTweak** and by extension the 'Word' tab ***still work*** on the discussion forums (I use them for my Greek course, which has no native 'Word' tab support). To keep the userscript working on my Firefox browser I recently had to change from Greasemonkey to Tampermonkey (these are extensions that enable userscripts) after their change from legacy add-ons to WebExtensions.

Comment: I just found an official statement that the discussion forum is being rewritten as well: https://www.duolingo.com/comment/23099431. "The Discussion and Words tabs are still under the old website, so you'll notice things like notifications opening in a popup instead of in the middle of your screen. Since the Forum is still quite slow, we are now focusing our attention on rewriting the Forum as well!" So the DuoTweak workaround is temporary. Sadly, the trick mentioned by @Turpidude doesn't work on the rewritten site either...